# Error function called when I parse the parameters using jquery AJAX function to asp.net behind code

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

This is my aspx page code

```
function grid(datas)
{
    var datass = {datas: datas};
    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(datass);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'EditCustomerBills.aspx/LoadGrid',
        method: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: myJSON,
        success: function (data) { 
           alert("Success");
        },
        error:function(error){
            alert("failed");
        }         

    });
}
```

and this is my behind code

```
[WebMethod]
public static string LoadGrid(string datas)
{
    //GetCustomerBillDetail(data);
    string datass = datas.ToString();
    return datass;
}
```

I'm using code perfectly, but output is failed. I'm struggling for four days. please help me. thank you.

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: Usually you dont need to add the aspx where you at in the URL of the ajax, you can simple do `/LoadGrid` and it should work. Also would be a lot of help if you just give us the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your "myJSON" is . according to me your code should be sometinhg like this.

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
 public static string GetCurrentTime(string datas)
    {
        return "Hello " + datas + Environment.NewLine + "The Current Time is: "
            + DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function ShowCurrentTime() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CS.aspx/GetCurrentTime",
        data: '{datas: "Your Data" }', // your data should be here.
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function(response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
}
function OnSuccess(response) {
    alert(response.d);
}
</script>
```

below picture will give you a idea how we can call the server side method.

[image]

for more reference please see [this](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

edit as follows and share with f12 in console output?

```
error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
```